# How to make an very extensive Squash and Stretch rig?

Tags: rigging

I would like to make a rig that behaves like this: https://youtu.be/QHsrRRfE8VY?t=41

So a extensive rig, that has on top of that an extensive squash and stretch functionality.

Should I somehow parent everything to a bone with a Stretch To -constraint or something?

[image]

Comment: Mesh deform modifier or maybe shape keys?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvVxhQ1O6bs&t

Comment: Great! That could be one way :)

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, I guess the universal stretch to -bone is one solution... maybe

[image]

With two stretchers it's way better, though:

[image]

Oh, but Bendy Bones might be even better for the main core rig.
**[This](https://github.com/gnastacast/bendy_bone_handles)** was an essential addon to make those bbones, then I just joined them together.

[image]

Oh yeah, progress:

[image]

Comment: What would you recommend after all your experimentation? I have something similar - a main rig composed of bendy bones, but then I'd like to add a "global" squash and stretch to the whole thing, exactly like you. Did you go with a main squash and stretch bone on top of the bendy bone rig, or a lattice deform around the bendy bone rig? Thanks!

Comment: @teeeeee Can't really remember what I did. But if I was to make a character now, I might add some of those little bendy bones with controls and on top of that some bigger (like you probably just said) and then even one universal one, yes - that might be good.